# Having 2 image picker and issue with didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I have two UIImageView , each of them should display different images from picker , but I can use one delegate : `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info ;`

here is my code :

```
- (void) importFormLibraryForCover {


    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0, 200,660);

    pop = [[ UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:ipc];
    [pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    [ipc release];


}

    - (void) importFormLibraryForAvatar {


//same above code 

}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


       avatarImg.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// here is the problem :
         coverImg.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];



    }
```

the problem is all two imageViews display same picture and Property 'tag' not found on object of type `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your own enum declare it in .h file.

```
typedef enum _Type
{
    eNone,
    eCover,
    eAvatar

}EType;
```

Also declare a variable `EType _type;` in .h file.
In the following method,

```
- (void) importFormLibraryForCover
{
  // set variable
  _type = eCover;
 ...
}
```

Similarly for other method, set other value.

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, check the `_type` and process as required.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead...  create a single object for the uiimagepickercontroller in the .h file and use it in both the cases by changing the source type and release it in the dealloc..

Comment: Property 'tag' not found on object of type 'UIImagePickerController

Comment: sorry my mistake .. UIImagePickerController doesn't have tag property.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom class of NSObject type.

This class will initialize the UIImagePicker controller and create a delegate that return the image.

And in the above code, create two instance of your custom class and differentiate them with any retain property variable.

Now in the delegate implementation, you will get the image and also the retain property. Based on the value, update your UI.

Hopes this helps. :)